# asp.net core razor page calling rest service and how to wait for response.

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await, webclient

I have a razor page that calls a rest service to find the geocodes for a supplied address. The call uses a event triggered callback when it completes the lookup. Everything is working, but the timing is off. By the time the callback finishes, the page is already drawn, and I need the results from the callback to properly draw the page.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Northwind.ModelsDB;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using BingMapsRESTToolkit;
using System.Net;

namespace Northwind.Pages.CustomerPages
{

public class DetailsModel : PageModel
{
  private readonly Northwind.ModelsDB.NorthwindContext _context;
  private readonly IOptions<MyConfig> config;
  public string BingMapKey { get; private set; }
  public double latitude { get; private set; }
  public double longitude { get; private set; }
  public string query { get; private set; }
  public VIndividualCustomer VIndividualCustomer { get; private set; }

  public DetailsModel(Northwind.ModelsDB.NorthwindContext context, IOptions<MyConfig> configg)
  {
     _context = context;
     this.config = configg;
     BingMapKey = config.Value.BingMapKey;
  }

  public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
  {
     if (id == null)
     {
        return NotFound();
     }

     VIndividualCustomer = await _context.VIndividualCustomer
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BusinessEntityId == id);

     if (VIndividualCustomer == null)
     {
        return NotFound();
     }

     query = VIndividualCustomer.AddressLine1 + " " +
        VIndividualCustomer.AddressLine2 + ", " +
        VIndividualCustomer.City + ", " +
        VIndividualCustomer.StateProvinceName + ", " +
        VIndividualCustomer.PostalCode;
     query = "1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA";
     Uri geocodeRequest = new Uri(string.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q={0}&key={1}", query, BingMapKey));
     GetResponse(geocodeRequest, (x) =>
     {
        var location = (BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location)x.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0];
        latitude = location.GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[0];
        longitude = location.GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[1];
     });

     return Page();
  }

  private void GetResponse(Uri uri, Action<Response> callback)
  {
     System.Net.WebClient wc = new WebClient();
     wc.OpenReadCompleted += (o, a) =>
     {
        if (callback != null)
        {
           DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
           callback(ser.ReadObject(a.Result) as Response);
        }
     };
     wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);


  }
```

}
}

Comment: Do you expect it to be a long wait or a short wait (short enough to disallow the user to do anything)?

Comment: Is just a few seconds. I need the lat/long to properly draw a map, otherwise I get a map with the lat/long=0, which is off the coast of Africa.

Answer (score 1):

Your method will never be updated because the response is already sent to the client.  You need to block the method (use HttpClient instead) and wait for the response:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
  // this "reads" better
  if (id.HasValue)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }

  VIndividualCustomer = await _context.VIndividualCustomer
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BusinessEntityId == id);

  if (VIndividualCustomer == null)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }

  query = VIndividualCustomer.AddressLine1 + " " +
    VIndividualCustomer.AddressLine2 + ", " +
    VIndividualCustomer.City + ", " +
    VIndividualCustomer.StateProvinceName + ", " +
    VIndividualCustomer.PostalCode;
  query = "1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA";

  // string interpolation
  //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated
  var url = $"http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q={query}&key={BingMapKey}";
  var geocodeRequest = new Uri(url);

  var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));

  var response = await (new HttpClient()).GetAsync(geocodeRequest);
  var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var x = ser.ReadObject(json) as Response;     

  var location = (BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location)x.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0];
  latitude = location.GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[0];
  longitude = location.GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[1];

  return Page();
}
```

Comment: That's a lot, that worked. I had to make one small change ... <code>//var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         System.IO.Stream json = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); </code>

Comment: Be sure that you *don't* create a new instance of `HttpClient` inline like in this example. See [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Answer (score 0):

The most closed code to your own code is this snippet:

```
    private async Task GetResponseAsync(Uri uri, Action<Response> callback) {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient wc = new HttpClient();
        var response = await wc.GetAsync(uri);
        if (callback != null) {
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
            callback(ser.ReadObject(stream) as Response);
        }
    }
```

and call it just like:

```
 await GetResponse(geocodeRequest, (x) =>
 {
    / bla bla bla...
 });
```

However, it's not a good refactored code. But can do the job.